# sliding menu move content to right before toggling

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm using the slide menu library and setting the menu offset from a xml.

```
setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
```

when I click the menu item I use

```
menu.toggle(true);
```

which moves the content to left with menu behind it. My scenario is when I click the menu item, the content has to move all the way to right and then should bring the content in like the normal way so that the user dont get to see the UI change. I used

```
setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_fullscreen);
showMenu(true);
```

where R.dimen.slidingmenu_fullscreen = 0dp. The menu goes to full screen behind the content, but the content doesn't moves to the right. Thanks in advance! 

**Edit 1**: This is similar to Xoom application... [Sample](http://tinypic.com/r/10i9op5/5) "Slide Sample"

Comment: @Binghammer Im just using this library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it myself.

```
menu.mViewAbove.scrollTo(menu.mViewAbove.getScrollX()-200,0);
```

moved the content to right. But now got into another problem. which I have descibed here->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714871/sliding-menu-move-content-to-right

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Use this [tutorial for sliding menu,](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/)  It is much easier to use, and you will find much more help with it. It is also more compatible with different screen sizes, and more Android versions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That's a very good tutorial, but right now I can't change into this. I only have to do some workaround in the existing code.